# Powershell/Batch file scripting - created time from file name

Tags: powershell, windows-10, metadata, batch-processing

I want to use a file name to set the metadata created time for over 6,000 images in one folder.
The file name usually starts with the letters "IMG" then the date and then the letters "WA" with 4 numbers to represent the number of the picture on that date
i.e. IMG-YYYYMMDD-WA????

I've tried with advanced renamer and got it to work on my pc but the minute i move it back over to my device (galaxy s9) the created time changes to the time i move it.

Is there a way i can script this in powershell or batch?

Comment: when you move the files back to your device, are you copy&pasting them or moving them?

Comment: Copying and pasting, sorry for the late response

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing the following:

```
robocopy SourcePath DestinationPath /COPY:DT /R:1 /W:1 /DCOPY:DT /LOG:%TEMP%\PhotoCopy.log /NP
```

This will COPY all of the files from SourcePath recursively to DestinationPath, maintaining timestamps, retrying only once on failure, copying directory timestamps, and writing a log file to your system's Temporary folder called Photocopy.Log while displaying no per-file progress.

Answer (score 0):

To change the CreationTime with PowerShell in place (adjust `X:\Path`)
without copying again:

```
Get-Chilitem X:\Path -File |
  Where-Object BaseName -match '^IMG-(\d{8})-WA\d{4}$' | 
    ForEach-Object {
      $_.CreationTime = [datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],'yyyyMMdd',$Null)
    }
```

- The script uses a RegEx to extract the date from the name and
  converts it to a `[datetime]`.
- In lack of hour, minute and second these are set to 00:00:00.
- The script doesn't care about the extension as long as the pattern
  `IMG-8digits-WA4digits` matches.

**PS: If the images aren't edited,**
LastWriteTime could still reflect the date the images are taken. In that case you could copy that with

```
$_.CreationTime = $_.LastWriteTime
```